# Runtime error appeared after updating to webpack 5. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

After upgrading my webpack from v4 to v5, I got this error that is getting me a hard time debugging.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
    at Module.UserEntity (main.9e5d0727.js:3998)
    at Module.<anonymous> (main.9e5d0727.js:5952)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime-main.9e5d0727.js:28)
    at fn (runtime-main.9e5d0727.js:308)
    at Module.<anonymous> (main.9e5d0727.js:5645)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime-main.9e5d0727.js:28)
    at fn (runtime-main.9e5d0727.js:308)
    at Module.<anonymous> (main.9e5d0727.js:4022)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime-main.9e5d0727.js:28)
    at fn (runtime-main.9e5d0727.js:308)
```

I compared my Sources tab between v4 and v5 webpack versions and I saw a difference in files that are generating using this command `cross-env NODE_ENV=local webpack serve --config ./config/webpack.config.js --progress --color`

[Webpack v4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9udc.png) [Webpack v5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHbGh.png)

Here is my current *webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const RemoveWebpackPlugin = require('remove-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

const styledComponentsTransformer = require('typescript-plugin-styled-components').default;
const webpack = require('webpack');

const configLocal = require(`./environments/env.local.js`);
const configCommon = require(`./environments/env.common.js`);

const rootPath = process.cwd();
const resolvePath = path.resolve.bind(rootPath);

const production = ['prod', 'production', 'master'].includes(NODE_ENV) ? 'production' : undefined;
const stage = ['staging', 'stage'].includes(NODE_ENV) ? 'staging' : undefined;
const development = ['development', 'dev'].includes(NODE_ENV) ? 'development' : undefined;
const local = 'local';
const ENVIRONMENT = production || stage || development || local;

const STAFF_OAUTH = process.env.STAFF_OAUTH || configLocal.STAFF_OAUTH;
const BACKEND_URL = process.env.BACKEND_URL ? `"${process.env.BACKEND_URL}"` : configLocal.BACKEND_URL;

const environment = {
  ...configCommon,
  ENVIRONMENT: `"${ENVIRONMENT}"`,
  SENTRY_URL: process.env.SENTRY_URL ? `"${process.env.SENTRY_URL}"` : undefined,
  BACKEND_URL,
  STAFF_OAUTH,
  SC_DISABLE_SPEEDY: true
};

const entryPoint = './src/index.tsx';

const config = {
  mode: production || stage ? 'production' : ENVIRONMENT === local ? 'none' : 'development',
  entry: production ? [entryPoint, require.resolve('./ym')] : entryPoint,

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[fullhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: ['node_modules', resolvePath('src')],
    fallback: { fs: false }
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        include: resolvePath('src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'thread-loader',
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              getCustomTransformers: () => ({
                before: [styledComponentsTransformer()]
              }),
              happyPackMode: true,
              transpileOnly: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.raw\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader',
            options: {
              esModule: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        exclude: /\.raw\.svg$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          esModule: false,
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'static/media/[name].[contenthash].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  optimization: {
    minimize: !!(production || stage),
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: entrypoint => `runtime-${entrypoint.name}`
    },
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },

  ignoreWarnings: [/export .* was not found in/],

  plugins: [
    // fix "process is not defined" error
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser'
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
          to: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')
        }
      ]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'src/index.html' }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(environment),
    new RemoveWebpackPlugin([path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'), path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.cache')], 'hide')
  ],

  devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    host: 'localhost',
    historyApiFallback: true
    // watchOptions: {
    //   ignored: resolvePath('cypress')
    // }
  },

  performance: {
    hints: false
  }
};

if (ENVIRONMENT === development || ENVIRONMENT === local) {
  config.devtool = 'source-map';
}

if (ENVIRONMENT === local) {
  const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

  config.plugins.push(
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      eslint: {
        files: './src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}'
      },
      typescript: {
        diagnosticOptions: {
          semantic: true,
          syntactic: true
        }
      }
    })
  );
} else {
  const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

  config.plugins.push(
    new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
      clientsClaim: true,
      skipWaiting: false,
      mode: production || stage ? 'production' : undefined,
      exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/, /LICENSE/]
    })
  );
}

module.exports = config;
```

And my *package.json* file

```
{
  "name": "dispatcher-service-front",
  "version": "1.27.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=local webpack serve --config ./config/webpack.config.js --progress --color",
    "start:ci": "webpack serve --config ./config/webpack.config.js",
    "build": "webpack --config ./config/webpack.config.js",
    "analyze": "webpack --profile --json > stats.json && webpack-bundle-analyzer stats.json"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,tsx}": "eslint -c .eslintrc.staged.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.13",
    "@types/react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "computed-async-mobx": "^6.1.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.6",
    "mobx": "^5.15.4",
    "mobx-react": "^6.2.2",
    "mobx-utils": "^5.5.7",
    "pik-front-utils": "git+https://gitlab+deploy-token-9:p1C2k__vanbHWx_ntuM_@git.pik.ru/pik-software/pik-front-utils.git#semver:1.0.3",
    "pik-ui-kit": "git+https://gitlab+deploy-token-8:gqgws4edpujq2MyATRR7@git.pik.ru/pik-software/pik-ui-kit.git#semver:1.10.3",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-is": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sanitize.css": "^12.0.1",
    "serializr": "^2.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript-ioc": "^3.2.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "cypress": "^8.6.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^35.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "remove-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.5",
    "thread-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.64.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.5.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1"
  }
}
```

My file structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2PK4.png)

I changed a few things according to [webpack 5 migration guide](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/)

1. In **config.output.filename** i changed
   `'static/js/[name].[hash:8].js'` => `'static/js/[name].[fullhash:8].js'`
2. Removed `node: { fs: 'empty' }` and added `fallback: { fs: false }` in **config.output.resolve**
3. **stats.warningFilter** renamed to **ignoreWarnings**
4. Added this plugin to fix *"process is not defined"* error

   ```
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser'
    }),
   ```
5. Redirected **index.html** file from *public* to *src* folder and changed a corresponding template in `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. I did that because there was a conflict on this file between `CopyWebpackPlugin` and `HtmlWebpackPlugin`
6. **devServer.contentBase** renamed to **devServer.static**
7. Commented **devServer.watchOptions** for now, because `watchOptions` key is no longer available
8. Removed two plugins `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` and `new HardSourceWebpackPlugin({ cacheDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.cache')`

That's it. Also, I compared how do files build between v4 and v5 versions using `webpack --config ./config/webpack.config.js` and there was no difference at all! Except in *index.html* file script tag were moved to `<head>`

Thanks for taking your time reading this, I will appreciate any help!

Comment: I am dealing with issues similar to this myself right now.

What I can say from looking at this error is that your UserEntity appears to be using a default import that is no longer being picked up as it should be.

This happened to me as well, and my solution was to copy over the imported code to get past that error and into the "real" stuff (I had about 15 errors being hidden after this one was taken away)

Comment: in my case error was from stylus-loader I had to bisect some code to find a reason - typo in *styl file, somebody place ```@image 'mixin.styl'``` instead of ```@import``` :) old loader skipped this typo, and new not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. In my case the problem was in importing class and use it as a type and for some reason it was making the error.

I fixed it by changing

```
import { UserEntity } from 'models';
```

to

```
import type { UserEntity } from 'models';
```

After that my runtime error disappeared

Answer (score 1):

For my version of this error, the issue seemed to be that I was importing a file with an alias in webpack from within the same directory.

To give an example, I had this directory setup:

```
~/utils (~ is aliased in my webpack)
  /fileWithTheImport.ts (
  /fileToImport.ts
  /index.ts (exports * from the other two files)
```

I was using `import { named } from ~/utils` initially and seeing the error.

Once I changed that import to `import { named } from './fileToImport.ts'` the error resolved and things worked as expected.

#### In your case

I see that it's having a hard time reading 'default', which would mean to me that the default import for UserEntity may have a similar problem to what I had.

I would try to remove any alias paths if UserEntity is in the same directory and hopefully your issue will go away.

Comment: Also fixed the same problem for me with parcel.js

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by `webpack-cli` version upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message but my problem was a circular dependency. Essentially I had something like this:

Contents of a.js:

```
import B from './b';
import C from './c';

export default function A() {
    C();
}
```

Contents of b.js:

```
import A from './a';

export const SOME_CONSTANT = {
   whatever: A(),
};
```

The problem is that Node is still trying to initialize a.js, and in doing so it got one of it's functions called before importing C. Specifically it's functions got called while importing B.

My fix was to re-order the imports in a.js:

```
import C from './c';
import B from './b';

export default function A() {
    C();
}
```